# inserting image at cursor position in javascript - displaying [object HTMLImageElement] instead of image

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to insert an image at the current location of a cursor but with my current code it is displaying: [object HTMLImageElement] instead of showing the actual image. 
This is what i have:

```
handleImage(picture){
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute('src', picture.url!);
        image.setAttribute('alt', picture.altText!);
        image.setAttribute('id', picture.id!.toLocaleString());
        var selection = document.getSelection()!;
        var cursorPos = selection.anchorOffset;
        var oldContent = selection.anchorNode.nodeValue!;
        var newContent = oldContent.substring(0, cursorPos) + image + oldContent.substring(cursorPos);
        selection.anchorNode.nodeValue = newContent;
    }
```

i believe the issue would be where var newContent is being set. I am not sure how to make it display the img instead of showing: [object HTMLImageElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to combine an image with a string. That won't work because JS does implicit type conversion. When you do `myStr + image` it's effectively the same as `myStr + image.toString()`. [object HTMLImageElement] is the string representation of an image element. There are a lotttt of unknowns in what you're trying to do (are you inserting into a text field? selected text?) but this is a basic solution:

```
handleImage(picture){
        var selection = document.getSelection()!;
        var cursorPos = selection.anchorOffset;
        var oldContent = selection.anchorNode.nodeValue!;
        var newContent = oldContent.substring(0, cursorPos) + `<img src="${picture.url}" alt="${picture.altText}" id="${picture.id!.toLocaleString()}">` + oldContent.substring(cursorPos);
        selection.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML = newContent;
}
```